# Device Managed SMR - How does controller detect empty space?

Tags: hard-drive

Does the controller of a device managed SMR hard disk detect a format (say with ExFat) and start writing with empty shindles?

I do encrypted Time Machine backups to an external SMR drive and recently learned about this technology. As the drive's controller only sees encrypted data, I think it can't detect when the drive gets emptied and it explains the abysmal performance of 5MB/s of the backups once the drive filled to 3TB capacity.

The USB 2 SATA controller does not use uasp and thus has not exposed TRIM to the OS. And OSX would also ignore it anyhow.

So while I copy my data to another drive I wonder how to reset the performance when I cannot send TRIM to the controller.

My thoughts were that the drive's controller maybe can also detect formatting but not when the data is encrypted. If not, I think these are the options:

- Formatting the drive with a filesystem that the controller detects (I try with ExFAT as the drive was shipped with this)
- ATA Secure Delete (would take 2 days to trigger this and any Linux documentation for this says that it is not wise to do this over USB2Sata controllers)
- Overwriting with zero. Maybe the controller also detects a pattern here and marks a complete shindle for garbage collection.

Unfortunately, the idea of device managed is that the user should not need to think about how  the drive handles the data. But when you want to reset the performance, it cannot be done without more details about the internal functions (that also seem to be protected as IP).

So my idea is that maybe the community already identified the behavior of SMR drives and can give points to what helps.

Furthermore what can be done to improve the situation in the future? These things come to my mind:

- Stay formatted with FAT32/ExFAT and handle encryption in a container (like Sparsebundle) in case the controller can look into simple filesystem structures or detect write patterns
- Keep free disk space by partitioning only 80% of the drive (like in the old days of SSDs to give the controller some leeway to restructure shindles and to avoid filling the disk to the brim and cause fragmentation)
- Don't hate SMR but deal with it's pros and cons and use a controller with TRIM support and enable it
- Maybe use such drives only for backups that are written in 128MB compressed volumes

Comment: Secure Erase should not take two days on any drive currently in existence. Where did you get that number from?

Comment: hdparm -I. But you are right the reported time was 860min.

Comment: That sounds a bit closer to correct for a multi terabyte spinning drive. It's fine to do Secure Erase over USB if the drive's USB-SATA controller supports UAS, which these days they all do, and you can supply power for those 14 hours.